# abs valus for complex matrix multipilication

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, python

I am a programmer with little math background. But recently there's a project requires me to do complex value matrix multiplication.
If I have a matrix $A$ and $B$, is the following equation true?
$||A\cdot B|| = ||A||\cdot ||B||$, where $||A||$ is the element-wise norm.

When I try to code out some examples, this equation sometimes holds sometimes doesn't.

### Case 1, if $A \in R^{1\times2} $ and $B \in R^{2\times1}$

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1+2j ,3-1j]])
b = np.array([[4+1j], [-1+1j]])

print(np.array_equal(abs(np.matmul(b,a)), (np.matmul(abs(b),abs(a)))))
>>> True
```

The equation holds.

### Case 2, if $A \in R^{2\times2} $ and $B \in R^{1\times2}$

```
a = np.array([[1+2j,3-1j], [-1j, 1+1j]])
b = np.array([[4+1j, -1+1j]])
print(np.array_equal(abs(np.matmul(b,a)),np.matmul(abs(b),abs(a))))
>>> False
```

The equation doesn't hold.

Why is it sometimes true and sometimes false?

### More background to my question

I am trying to implement an algorithm proposed by [Judith C. Brown in 1992](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/628a/0981e2ed1c33b1b9a88018a01e2f0be0c956.pdf)
[image]
In my case, $x[n]$ and $y^*[n]$ are given. My target is to get $||Z||$. When I was referring to existing codes, I see two versions.

1. The first version is to get $||X[k]||$ and $||Y[k]||$, then multiply them together and assume the result is already $||Z||$.
2. The second version is to multiply $X[k]$ and $Y[k]$ in their complex number form to obtain another complex matrix $Z$, then they do $||Z||$ to get the result.

I don't know which approach is correct, since I don't know Parseval's equation. When I google Parseval's equation, it shows me $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n\bar{b_n}=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}A(x)\bar{B(x)dx}$ instead.

Comment: How do you define $\lVert A\rVert$?

Comment: $||A||$ is the element-wise norm, I have added the clarification to the question.

Comment: A norm on a complex vector space $V$ is a map $||\cdot || : V \to \mathbb{C}$. Your "norm" is a map from $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ to $M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$. Now, to your question. The equation doesn't hold because absolute value is not linear (i.e. it is not true that $|z+w| =|z| + |w|$ in general). Just write down two arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrices and convince yourself that this is what you have assumed.

Comment: I have added more background information on what I am trying to achieve.
What confuses me is that I saw some people calculate the element-wise norm for $X$ and $Y$ and multiply them together. And some people multiply $X$ and $Y$ first to obtain a new matrix $Z$. Then they do element-wise norm on $Z$. To me, it seems the latter approach should be the author's original intention?

Answer (score 1):

That equation is not correct. Using induced matrix norms, you should get an inequality. $||AB||\leq ||A||||B||$. For frobenius norm (an elementwise norm), this also holds.

For what you are doing, it appears the inequality should hold elementwise. You are simply replacing each  element of  the matrix with its norm, before calculating the matrix product. This should force each element of the resulting matrix to be larger or equal to the corresponding product in the original matrix multiplication.